# Python Threading.Timer is calling command without waiting

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I have a very basic Tkinter application that I'm trying to set to automatically refresh.  I am using threading.Timer to trigger a function called go at the end of which cocalls the timer to reset it to run again.

```
def SetTimer():
    t=threading.Timer(5,go())
    t.start
    SetTimer()
```

I've spent most of my afternoon trying to resolve this but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Based upon the other questions I've read I understand that each instance creates a separate thread with the timer, but why isn't it waiting for the time to elapse prior to triggering the function.

Comment: If you're using Tkinter, using a thread to automatically refresh is the wrong way to solve the problem. You can avoid the complexities of threads by calling the `after` method of the root widget (or any widget) to schedule a function to run in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
t=threading.Timer(5,go)
```

Note the `go` rather than `go()`. The parentheses tell Python to call the function. In contrast, `go` is a function object. Functions are "first-class" objects in Python; they can be passed to functions just like any other object.

Python evaluates the arguments to a function before calling the function. So using `go()` calls the `go` before calling `threading.Timer`. The value returned by `go()` gets sent to `Timer`, which is not what you want.

---

Note that all Tkinter UI code should be called from a single thread. For this reason, using Tkinter's `root.after` method is probably a better choice for what you want to do. The `after` method schedules a function to be called by Tkinter's `mainloop`. Here are some examples using `after`:

- [Tkinter and Threads](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-threads.htm)
- [A rotating image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15736974/190597)

Comment: That makes perfect sense!  Thank you for your help!