# Python: Advice on implementing threads in my GUI application

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface

I am really struggling at implementing threads into my application. This might get kind of long so please bear with me.  My questions are more around the suggested structure of my application than it is around the code to add threading.

First let me show a visual of my application.  Than explain a few things.  The application is fed data via an Arduino on the serial port.  In a nut shell I open a serial port, read the data line by line, process it and show it visually on the screen.  The visuals are two parts. The first is the time for each racer that is kept and passed via the serial port by the Arduino.  The second it the race progress based on the distance of the race that is represented in the clock style hands you see also see in the screen shot.  This all happens real time and the data coming from the Arduino via the serial port happens very fast.

[image]

Once the race is started this function is how I parse the data and tell the system what to do with the data.

```
def letsrace(self):
    def getsome():
        global var1, var2, totalCount
        self.reset() 
        self.senddemo()
        letsRace = 1
        ser.write('!g\n')
        while (letsRace == 1):
            #print mycount
            s = ser.readline()
            s = s.strip('\r\n')
            #Check for :          
            pattern = r'[:]'
            if re.search(pattern, s):
                #print 'VALID : %r' % (s,)
                var1, var2 = s.split(":")
                self.options[var1]()
            else:
                #print 'INVALID : %r' % (s,)
                pass
            if totalCount == 4:
                letsRace = 0
        self.racecomplete()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=getsome)
    thread.start()
```

As you can see I do have a thread going.  This worked great since displaying the timer for each racer was bogging down the application.  I have had no problem once I added the threading on the race function.

I should also point out that I use a dictionary as a case statement.  It is up in the ini of a Race class. It looks like this below.

```
    self.options = {"0": self.draw_r1,
        "1": self.draw_r2,
        "2": self.draw_r3,
        "3": self.draw_r4,
        "0f": self.racerFinish,
        "1f": self.racerFinish,
        "2f": self.racerFinish,
        "3f": self.racerFinish,
        "x": self.emptyLine,
        "t": self.raceTime,
        "G": self.letsGo,
        "CD": self.countDown,
        "C": self.emptyLine,
        }
```

Based on what I parse from the real-time data stream I process it with the correct function. Pretty basic stuff so far I think you will agree.

I just completed the code to add in the racer dials on top of the clock-style display. I am using Pillow (PIL) to rotate the dials.  This is also pretty basic stuff. I have a canvas and I added four images to the canvas to represent each racer.   I use a different function for each racer to update their position in the race.  They are the first four functions you see in the dictionary above. Here is an example of one of them.  They are all pretty much the same other than what image they are updating on the clock.

```
    def draw_r4(self):
    if self.r4_isdone == 0:
        self.angle = (float(var2) * self.movement ) * -1 
        if self.angle < -360:
           self.angle = 0
        self.canvas.delete(self.canvas_obj4)
        self.newarrow4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image_r4.rotate(self.angle))
        self.canvas_obj4 = self.canvas.create_image(215, 215, image=self.newarrow4)
```

If you are familiar with PIL and rotating an image you  know that it basically redraws the graphic over and over to show the new positions. Here is where the system now has issues.  On a Win8 or Mac the dials don't really impact the performance of the application.   On a Raspberry PI with limited processing power it does. A demo race takes about 6.4 seconds to complete but on a RPi it take about 15 seconds due to the processing of the image redraws. To get this working on something like the Raspberry I'd like to have each dial animation running in its own thread.

So, if you are still reading this great.  I apologize for the length. Now my question.  How would you suggest I get each dial movement into its own thread?  Keep in mind that the main racing function above has a thread.  Every threading example I have read is so basic that implementing anything in a full gui application has my head spinning a bit.

Comment: Are you creating new images during each frame of animation? I don't see anywhere in the draw code where you delete old objects before creating new ones.

Comment: I should point out that the four functions that redraw the dial positions are called 100s maybe even well over 1000 times in the process of a race. It will depend on the race distance. I have tried to wrap each draw function in a thread like the race function but that obviously doesn't help due to them being called so many times during the course of a race.

Comment: Bryan, granted my knowledge is limited but I don't think you have to delete it. I just kind of thought that PIL took care of that of you.  If it was not deleting them wouldn't they all be on the screen as the new one is drawn?

Comment: Bryan, I just looked at a few examples and this one does delete it each time.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736530/python-tkinter-rotate-image-animation    So if it is not visible on the screen and it is not deleted where is it?  Just in memory some place slowing things down?

Comment: I updated the code to have the delete in it but it doesn't impact the speed of the dials.

Comment: If you don't delete it,it remains in the memory of the canvas. The canvas has known performance issues when there are lots of items (where "lots" is defined as thousands or perhaps tens of thousands). If you keep adding items and never delete them, the canvas will get slower over time.

Comment: You're not likely to get a performance increase by multithreading, since you're going to be using the same amount of processor time as you would have without threading (plus some overhead for context switching). You may however, get more reasonable I/O processing (if your I/O is being blocked by processing or vice versa, threading may help you out).

Comment: Also, drawing into an image is particularly slow. You might want to consider creating the various images ahead of time and then just swapping the images out. Or, just draw the objects directly on the canvas rather than using images.