# Rotating tkinter canvas by a particular angle

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, rotation

I am trying to use the code at [Python Tkinter rotate image animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736530/python-tkinter-rotate-image-animation?rq=1) with the following change:

Instead of rotating the canvas endlessly, I want a rotation of "turn" degrees which is randomly decided using randint() function. However, after turning by this angle, the tkinter window disappears and an error is raised. How can I make the following code work.

From my intermediate level knowledge of Python, I can see that the "yield" statement is putting a generator to work.

You can use any image in place of "0.png" in my code. I am using Python 3.9.6. Thanks in advance. The following is the code I am trying to get to work.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from time import sleep
from random import randint

class SimpleApp(object):
  def __init__(self, master, filename):
    self.master = master
    self.filename = filename
    self.canvas = Canvas(master, bg="black", width=500, height=500)
    self.canvas.pack()

    self.update = self.draw().__next__
    master.after(100, self.update)

  def draw(self):
    image = Image.open(self.filename)
    angle = 0
    turn = randint(30, 390)
    
    for i in range(turn):
      tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.rotate(angle))
      canvas_obj = self.canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=tkimage)
      self.master.after_idle(self.update)
      yield
      self.canvas.delete(canvas_obj)
      angle = (angle - 1) % 360
      sleep(.01)

win = Tk()
app = SimpleApp(win, '0.png')

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: `import *` is not preferred. See more [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: after last `yield` it exits function draw  and then `__next__` can't run it again and it raise `StopIteration` and you should simply use `try/except` to catch it.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I "tried" try / catch, but that too did not work. I got the following error message:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 814, in callit
    func(*args)
StopIteration

Answer (score 1):

After last `yield` it exits function `draw` in normal way and then `__next__()` can't run it again and it raises `StopIteration` and this makes problem. Normally when it is used in `for`-loop then it catchs `StopIteration`. Or if you run it with `next()` then you can also catch `StopIteration` but in this example it is problem.

I would do it without `yield`. I would split it in two functions: `draw()` to set default values at start, and `rotate()` to update image.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from time import sleep
from random import randint

class SimpleApp(object):
    
  def __init__(self, master, filename):
      self.master = master
      self.filename = filename
    
      self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, bg="black", width=500, height=500)
      self.canvas.pack()
    
      self.draw()

  def draw(self):
      self.image = Image.open(self.filename)
      self.angle = 0
      self.turn = randint(30, 360)
      self.canvas_obj = None
      self.master.after(100, self.rotate)
    
  def rotate(self):
      # it will remove image after last move
      #if self.canvas_obj:
      #   self.canvas.delete(self.canvas_obj)
         
      if self.turn > 0:
          # it will NOT remove image after last move
          if self.canvas_obj:
              self.canvas.delete(self.canvas_obj)

          self.tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image.rotate(self.angle))
          self.canvas_obj = self.canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=self.tkimage)
        
          self.angle = (self.angle - 1) % 360
          self.turn -= 1
          self.master.after_idle(self.rotate)
        
win = tk.Tk()
app = SimpleApp(win, 'lenna.png')
win.mainloop()
```

`lenna.png` - (Wikipedia [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna))

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's just the kind of help I was looking for, but couldn't get around doing on my own. Will study it to understand it better. Thanks again.