# How can I get the image in the button to rotate on click in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to classes and am working on a program in tkiter and python. How do I get this image to change into a rotated image on click. The error says that rotate is not defined so i cannot do .rotate to th image. please help me solve this issue.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("65x65+1475+756")
        self.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "green")

        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="sharingan.png")
        self.btn = Label(image=self.photo, bd=0, command = sharingan_animation_onclick)
        self.btn.pack()
        self.overrideredirect(True)

    def __int__(self):
        rotated_sharingan1 = self.photo.rotate(90, PIL.Image.NEAREST, expand = 1)
        Image.open(rotated_sharingan1)


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think there is no rotate method. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736530/python-tkinter-rotate-image-animation to rotate the image (Including animation)

Comment: `PIL.Image` module has an [image rotation function](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.rotate).

Comment: oh okay thanks. I get it now