# How should I go about creating a custom, rotated text box with a custom font and custom input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a script to type in a conlang, it makes heavy use of chording so I will be using python to interpret the keyboard input and turn it into text. My main problem is the conlang is vertical; from the bottom to the top. All I need to do is use a custom font and rotate the text 90 degrees and it will work perfectly, but that seems to be near impossible.

- a.) it needs to be rotated
- b.) it needs to be updated in real time
- c.) it needs to be updated by the script, not an integrated text box
- d.) it needs to use a custom font file

I've tried using tkinter, but there does not seem to be an option to rotate text (people have referenced an option to do that, but not explained how to actually enable that) most other methods deal with rendering an image and then rotating it, which I would like to avoid, I am also not sure how to update text in tkinter, so that is an additional problem.

Comment: You could try using Pillow to draw the text. Rendering it with Pillow should allow you to perform rotation, and then with tk.PhotoImage you can draw the updated image to the screen. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736530/python-tkinter-rotate-image-animation